# Error when install GTK+ 3.0.5 on CentOS

Tags: linux, gtk

Got below error when installing gtk+-3.0.5 from source code on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503.

**Error msg:**

> /usr/bin/ld: queryimmodules.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   'g_module_close' /usr/bin/ld: note: 'g_module_close' is defined in DSO
>   /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
>   /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**Environment:**

> [root@localhost gtk+-3.0.5]# cat /etc/*release CentOS Linux release
>   7.1.1503 (Core)
>
> CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7" CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
>   REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
>
> CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)  CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503
>   (Core)
>
> [root@localhost gtk+-3.0.5]# uname -a Linux localhost.localdomain
>   3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-building.html

**./configure --prefix=/opt/gtk**

> ## GTK+ 3.0.5
>
> GDK backends:         x11 X11 extensions:       XKB XI2 XFIXES DAMAGE
>   Print backends:       file lpr Dynamic modules:      yes Included
>   immodules:   none PackageKit support:   yes Introspection:        no
>   Debugging:            minimum Documentation:        no

**Make**

> ...   CCLD   libgtk-3.la   CC     queryimmodules.o   CCLD
>   gtk-query-immodules-3.0 /usr/bin/ld: queryimmodules.o: undefined
>   reference to symbol 'g_module_close' /usr/bin/ld: note:
>   'g_module_close' is defined in DSO /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 so try
>   adding it to the linker command line /lib64/libgmodule-2.0.so.0: could
>   not read symbols: Invalid operation collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status make[4]: *** [gtk-query-immodules-3.0] Error 1 make[4]:
>   Leaving directory `/root/gtk/gtk+-3.0.5/gtk' make[3]: ***
>   [all-recursive] Error 1 make[3]: Leaving directory`
>   /root/gtk/gtk+-3.0.5/gtk' make[2]: *** [all] Error 2 make[2]: Leaving
>   directory `/root/gtk/gtk+-3.0.5/gtk' make[1]: *** [all-recursive]
>   Error 1 make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/gtk/gtk+-3.0.5' make: ***
>   [all] Error 2

Comment: Either your GLib is too old, or the Makefile that that version of GTK+ generates forgot to link GLib into the IM Modules. I'm not sure which it is. You can run a `nm`  on `libgmodule.so` to see if it has those symbols, which would confirm whether it is the former. That being said, why are you trying to build such an ancient version of GTK+ on a version of CentOS released several months ago? The package manager likely comes with 3.14 or 3.16, which has lots of wonderful features in comparison to 3.0.5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

`# yum install gtk3-devel` ... will provide version `-3.8.8-10.el7`

? Why do you want to use an old version ? Time stamp = 23 March 2011 !

---